# WPF Triggering by ancestral property

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, findancestor

I would like to use a trigger, but need to select the ancestor's property, for example:

```
<Trigger Property="State" Value="Expanded">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</Trigger>
```

Only that the State property need to be the property of an unknown ancestor by a known Type
and if could not be found then trigger would never execute.

So my question is how can I find the ancestor to get the property to use in the trigger?

Hope I made myself clear.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Whatever}}}" Value="Expanded">
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. No need for FindAncestor since it is default. Thank you.